# Convert string to doubles in a .txt file?

Tags: java, parsing, split, java.util.scanner, printwriter

I have a .txt file of numbers that are formatted like the following:

`1.2 2.3 3.4 4.5
2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0`

I'm trying to use a scanner to take each line as a string, convert each number to a double and then add them together to print to a new .txt file. 
My error message looks like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "1.2 2.3 3.4 4.5"     at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)   at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)     at
>   scanstrings.ScanStrings.parseDouble(ScanStrings.java:51)  at
>   scanstrings.ScanStrings.main(ScanStrings.java:33)

I was trying to use a split to separate each number so that they could be converted to doubles, but no matter what I do nothing seems to work, and I've found ways to split using spaces and periods but each way I try returns the same error message.

My code basically looks like this right now (I'm just starting so I'm sorry if it's just bad, I've also been messing with this for a while so some parts might just not make sense

```
 //Construct Scanner object for the input file 
    Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("one.txt"));

    //Construct Scanner object for the output file
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("result.txt");

    //Read lines from the input file

    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        String line = input.nextLine();

        String[] conv = line.split("\\s+");
        String dub1 = conv[0];
        String dub2 = conv[1];
        String dub3 = conv[2];
        String dub4 = conv[3];


        //convert to double
        double dub = parseDouble(line);

        //compute sum
        double total = 0;
        if (dub != 0) //protect against division by zero
        {
            total += dub;
        }
        System.out.printf("\n", dub, total);
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();     
}

public static double parseDouble(String conv) throws NumberFormatException{
    int i = 0;
    while (!Character.isDigit(conv.charAt(i))) { i++; }
    return Double.parseDouble(conv.substring(i).trim());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You've split your line into individual terms, but then are passing the whole line to your parsing with this:

```
double dub = parseDouble(line);
```

Instead, try:

```
double dub = parseDouble(conv[0]);
```

for the first value.  (You may even want to try creating a loop, for all values.)

Comment: The loops I make don't really work for this. I've also changed this in my program, and it now runs but doesn't successfully print into a new .txt file with the printwriter. I'm gonna keep trying!

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you only ask one question at a time.  But, to be helpful: Your printing issue stems from using `System.out.printf` instead of `output.printf`.  Ask a new question about PrintWriter, if you need more help with that; this question and answers should stay focused on your NFE issue.

Answer (score 0):

(as far as i understood you wish to add the numbers in each line from input file, and print it on new line, in output file). An easier way would be to rely on `Double.parseDouble(String)` to convert the string to `Double`. New version of your `parseDouble(line)`

```
public static double parseDouble(String line){
   double res = 0;
   for(String number : line.split("\\s+") ){
       try{
              res += Double.parseDouble(number);
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException ex){
              System.out.println("Cannot convert " + number + " to double");
       }
       finally{
              return res;
       }
   }
```

So in that case, you should rename your `parseDouble(String line)` to `getSum(String line)`